# Setting MySQL/MariaDB data directory to a directory in `home`, how can I make sure the `/home` is mounted before mysql daemon starts at boot time

Tags: systemd, opensuse, mysql, mariadb

On openSUSE Leap 15, I install MariaDB by:

```
> sudo zypper in mariadb
```

Right after installing MariaDB and right before starting it, I add this line to `/etc/my.cnf`, to set the MariaDB data directory to be in my `home` directory:

```
datadir = /home/me/mysql/data
```

Then I start MariaDB by running two commands:

```
> sudo rcmysql start
> /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

My home directory mounts separately:

```
> lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    40G  0 part /var
├─sda3   8:3    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda4   8:4    0 883.1G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

How can I make sure that the `/home` is mounted before `mysql` daemon tries to start at boot time?

Comment: Mounts in fstab are handled fairly early in the boot process. If you are  having *any* specific problem when booting please add them to the question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks. I don't have any specific problem. I just thought I might run into problems in future. But based on your comment, I feel like there is nothing to be worry about, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with OpenSuSE, but I think that version is already based on `systemd`, so why not override the unit responsible for starting MariaDB and add a prerequisite to wait for the mounting of `/home`?